# How to add php 7 extensions using remi on CentOS 7

Tags: php, centos, php-extension

Please help with php 7 extensions on CentOS 7.

When trying to isntall extension, for example memcache and memcached using the command `yum --enablerepo=remi-php74 install php-memcache php-memcached` I got the message that this packages are already installed. 
`php --modules` also shows they are present. But I can't find them in `/etc/opt/remi/php74/php.d` and `/opt/remi/php74/root/lib64/php/modules`.

I attached screenshot of phpinfo() as well [phpinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuCoX.png), there are no additional extensions...
Please advice what I'm doing wrong, I'm not very strong in this DevOPS things :-)

Also added php --ini response [php --ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh1Tt.png)

Comment: What does `php --ini` show?

Comment: Added a screen with php --ini response to the post.

Comment: So looks like you have 2 versions of PHP installed. One for CLI and one for apache. Apache is running `/etc/opt/remi/php74/` and CLI is running `/etc/php.d/`. Your CLI also could be running a different PHP version, run `php -r "phpinfo();" | grep 'PHP Version'` to verify that.

Comment: Result of ```php -r "phpinfo();" | grep 'PHP Version'``` is:
    ```PHP Version => 7.4.27```
    ```PHP Version => 7.4.27```

Comment: Okay, so that's the same. `php -r "phpinfo();" | grep 'Configuration File (php.ini)'` matches apache output?

Comment: Nooo, for apache it's ```/etc/opt/remi/php74``` and ```grep 'Configuration File (php.ini)``` shows ```Path => /etc```.

Comment: So yes, you have 2 versions running. Your command line installed for CLI. That's why apache doesnt show them. Go to `/etc/php.d/` and you'll see them. Do you need both? Probably be better of using one for both.

Answer (score 0):

For a proper installation please follow the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions

If you need a single version, **php-*** packages are simpler to install and use

If you need multiple versions, **php74-php-*** are available

You can read the repository FAQ: [Difference between php-* and php##-php-* packages ?](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#scl)

So as you are running **php74-php** you need

```
yum install php74-php-pecl-memcache php74-php-pecl-memcached
```

But if you need a single version, probably better to remove all php74* packages and only use php-* ones.

Comment: A list of install packages may help (rpm -qa 'php*')